# Changing font in a single vue component using vuetify

Tags: vue.js, sass, fonts, vuetify.js

Im new to vue and especially new to vuetify.

Im looking for a solution to change the fonts of an individual component. Before using vuetify I simply added the font in
component with style scoped

```
<style scoped>

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Krona+One&display=swap');

html {
  font-family: 'Krona One', sans-serif;
}
```

After I added vuetify this is no longer possible. So far I managed to change the global font with a main.scss and a variables.scss file and I imported it in my main.js file.

main.scss

```
@import '../scss/variables.scss';
```

variables.scss

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Krona+One&display=swap');
$body-font-family: 'Krona One', sans-serif
```

But I don't get it how to change the font of an individual component like just for my header component (Toolbar/Navigationbar)

Comment: Simply use a CSS selector that targets the root tag of your component as opposed to targeting the `html` tag.